# C++ Template: Partial template Function Specialization in template class

Tags: c++, templates, linker-errors, template-specialization

I want to specialize specific function in template class.

Eg:

```
template<class T>
class A   
{    
public :  
  void fun1(T val);  
  void fun2(T val1, T val2);
};

template <class T>
void A<T>::fun1(T val)
{
  // some task 1;
}


template <class T>
void A<T>::fun2(T val1, T val2)
{
  // some task 2;
}


template <>
void A<char*>::fun2(char* val1, char* val2)
{
  // some task 2 specific to char*;
}
```

when I do something like this, I get error saying multiple definition for fun2()
Please let me why this wrong and also the correct way to implement this.

Comment: Compiled and linked successfully for me [http://ideone.com/zTdcB](http://ideone.com/zTdcB).

Comment: @ks1322, that's because you haven't involved multiple files in ideone. You can try to declare this code in .h file and then include that in 2 .cpp files. You will get linker error.

Comment: @Rahul the redefinition error (depends on a compiler) is due to the fact that in your full specialization a.k.a explicit specialization you're providing as a template param char* and when this param is substituted during initialization of primary template then there is fun2 already decl/def and T will be substituted for char*

Comment: @Rahul what you should do is to provide full class template specialization for char* and there define fnc fun2 with char* as arguments.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your method `fun2()` is *not a* `template` method as itself, though it's a member of a `template` class. I don't find the proper technical term but in simple words, specializing `fun2()` will create an effect of a normal function definition. Putting the definition in header file will give you multiple definition error.

To solve this problem, **just put an `inline` keyword** and the linker error will go away!

```
template <> inline // <----- 'inline' will prompt to generate only 1 copy
void A<char*>::fun2(char* val1, char* val2)
{
  // some task 2 specific to char*;
}
```

**Edit**: This solves the linker error. But still you cannot use the `A<char*>::fun2`. Ultimately it boils down to the very fact that you **need to specialize** the whole `class A<char*>` or **overload** the `fun2(char*, char*)` within `A<T>`

```
template<class T>
class A
{
  // constructors
public:
  //...
  void fun2(char* val1, char* val2)
  {
    //specific case when T = char*
  }
};
```

Answer (score 4):

I would suggest the following approach. Define a `private` function template called `implementation` to handle the general case, and *overload* (**not** *specialize*) `implementation` to handle the specific case when `T=char*`. Then from `fun2()`, call `implementation` passing a third argument as shown below. The correct `implementation` will be selected based on the template argument `T`:

```
template<class T>
class A   
{    
    template<typename U> struct selector{};

    public :  
        void fun1(T val);  
        void fun2(T val1, T val2)
        {
            //forward the call
            //a correct function will be selected automatically based on T
            implementation(val1, val2, selector<T>());
        }
   private:
        template<typename U>
        void implementation(T & val1, T & val2, const selector<U> &)
        {
           //general case!
        }
        void implementation(T & val1, T & val2, const selector<char*> &)
        {
           //specific case when T = char*
        }
};
```

The third argument of type `selector<T>` (or `selector<char*>`) helps selecting the correct implementation.

Comment: and this I believe is best approach for this kind of scenario although some people like to provide different specializations +1.

Answer (score 1):

Split your code accordingly and it should work, for example:

A.h

```
template<class T>
class A   
{    
    public :  
        void fun1(T val);  
        void fun2(T val1, T val2);

};

template <class T>
void A<T>::fun1(T val)
{
  // some task 1;
}


template <class T>
void A<T>::fun2(T val1, T val2)
{
  // some task 2;
}
```

A.cpp

```
#include <iostream>
#include "A.h"

template <>
void A<char *>::fun2(char* val1, char* val2)
{
  // some task 2 specific to char*;
  std::cout << "char*::fun2" << std::endl;
}
```

Amain.cpp

```
#include <iostream>    
#include "A.h"

int main()
{
  A<char*> a;

  char* c= 0;
  char* d= 0;

  a.fun2(c, d);
}
```

Compile and link, and it should do the right thing...

Comment: Hi,  Thanks for the reply. I just made fun2() inline and worked fine.